# Condition for abelian subgroup to be normal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Sorry for any mistakes I make here, this is my first post here.  I have a group $G$ which has an abelian subgroup $A<G$.  I also know there is a irreducible character $\chi$ with the degree of $\chi$ equal to the index of $A$ in $G$. This implies $G$ has a non-identity abelian NORMAL subgroup? How?

This is exercise 2.17 from Isaacs's Character Theory of Finite Groups, [page 31](http://books.google.com/books?id=fqKQIf4Kd_0C&pg=PA31).

The hint is to show that $\chi$ vanishes on $G-A$.

Comment: I always forget the tricks for character theory. I don't know how much of help this is, and I'll try to back it up with a page reference, but I can almost guarantee you this is in the "Normal Subgroups" chapter of Isaac's *Character Theory*. Have you tried looking there?

Comment: Where is this from? Also, as stated, it is trivial, since the trivial subgroup is an abelian normal subgroup of any group. Do you mean that A must be normal, or that G must have an abelian normal subgroup of the same order as A?

Comment: I was going to post an answer that, at the end, used the Chermak-Delgado measure (See section 1G in Isaacs's *FGT*), but Nicky's comment that this is an exercise in the beginning of Isaacs's Character Theory book shows this is definitely not the right approach.

Comment: @SteveD: I wouldn't mind seeing it.  I think if characters are mentioned, then characters should be used in the official answer, but alternatives might teach us a thing or two as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exercise (2.17) of Isaacs' *Character Theory of Finite Groups*. With Lemma (2.29) of that book you can see that $\chi$ vanishes outside $A$. Now look at the subgroup $N = \langle g \in G : \chi(g) \neq 0 \rangle$. Obviously $N \subseteq A$ hence $N$ is abelian. This subgroup is normal (conjugation does not change the character value) and non-trivial (otherwise the irreducible $\chi$ would vanish outside the identity element which is nonsense).

Comment: It is not immediate that $N$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @SteveD: It is immediate, but only because he has N be the subgroup generated by those g.  All the generators lie inside A, so N lies inside A.

Comment: Ahh, yes, OK, I thought he was just talking about the set of such $g$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the approach I mentioned in the comments above:

We have an abelian subgroup $A<G$, and we also have an irreducible character $\chi$ such that $\chi(1)=[G:A]$. From Lemma 2.29 in Isaacs, we see that $\chi$ must be zero outside of $A$.  Now if the center of the character $Z(\chi)$ is non-trivial, then it is a normal subgroup of $G$, contained in $A$, so we are done.

Otherwise $Z(\chi)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$, and thus by Corollary 2.30 in Isaacs, we have $[G:A]^2 < |G|$, or equivalently, $|A|^2>|G|$.  Now if we let $m(\cdot)$ be the Chermak-Delgado measure on $G$, then $m(A)\ge |A|^2>|G|$, and so if $M$ is the Chermak-Delgado subgroup, $m(M)>|G|$.  Since $m(\lbrace1\rbrace)=|G|$, we must have $M$ is non-trivial.